# Creating and testing that a database field has been created or not in same program

Tags: python, selenium

While writing a selenium test case,I have found out a weird situation
I was saving a form , and at the time of saving the form, I created a user into the database.
Now what is happening that user has been created successfully in the database but at the time of getting it in that same selenium test case I am getting `DOESNOTEXIST` exception. when I check manaually in the database, the newly created user is there.
Can anybody explain how can I create and test that user has been created or not on DB in same program ? and if it is not possible than Why ?

Comment: Does your DB use transactions? If so, are you sure that transaction that created user is committed at a time you tried to query it from DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, Actually problem was the `transaction handling`. Through out the program django uses auto_commit transaction so database change was happening only after program executed completely. So instead of auto_commit I am handling transaction manually by using `transaction.commit_manually` and `transaction.commit()` and `transaction.rollback()` to properly commit and rollback transactions at the point where I want them to save.